What is the site's policy on users who never vote?
What is the site's policy on users who never vote?
Here is an example of a user who has been on the site for over two years and has over 500 reputations, but who has never cast a single vote.
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/28926/marmayogi?tab=topactivity
Is, it fine? I do not think so.

We do not have a strict policy to take action against users who do not vote on posts. In other words, voting is not mandatory.
What we can do is encourage users to cast votes explaining the significance of it.
Following are some useful articles/pots which can be used while explaining users.

Blog Post from 2010 by Co-Founder of Stack Exchange
Posts from MSE discussing on motivation to vote
Referring to Help Center Article on importance of Voting:


Why is voting important?
Voting is central to our model of providing quality questions and answers; it is how …
...good content rises to the top
...incorrect content falls to the bottom
...users who consistently provide useful content accrue reputation and are granted more privileges on the site
It’s only through voting that a class of editors, closers, and moderators can emerge to help run and govern the site. Voting is how site leadership forms. That’s why the reputation leagues show a breakdown of top users by reputation for the week, month, quarter, year, or all time.

In the brief, voting is so important that without it the whole concept of quality and governing/moderating the site will fail!
One of such tool (below screenshot) which remind users who are not voting to vote on the posts has been just announced yesterday! You can read more about it in Meta Stack Overflow




I think all users understand that voting keeps the site running. If someone does not vote that means he is a parasite.

Ha ha. Now, you can't see how many votes a user has cast! Wow! Safe heaven for Parasites!

@AmritenduMukhopadhyay Knowledge is unlimited. So, there is no definition of parasite here! "Purnamadah Purnamidam..."

I guess, you are one of those!
